# using ajax in codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

**ReferenceError: status_change is not defined**
***j-query function is not working***
**This is view page**
I want when selecting any value from dropdown list the status_change function will work
)">

```
                    <option value="0" <?php echo ($row['block']==0?'selected':'');?>>Unblock</option>
                    <option value="1" <?php echo ($row['block']==1?'selected':'');?>>Block</option>
                    </select>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){


    function status_change(status,user_id)
    {
        alert(status+'------'+user_id);

    }





    /*$('#status').change(function(status,user_id){
        var a=$('#status').val();
        alert(status+'------'+user_id);
        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"<?php//echo base_url() ?>index.php/admin/admin_school_controller/block",
            data:{status:a},
            success:function(data)
            {
                location.reload();
            }
        });

    });*/
});
```

Comment: Include jquery library before  that script.

Answer (score 0):

Why define a function inside $(document).ready() ? There is no need to do that. If you have to do it inside ready(), then do it like this :

```
  <script type="text/javascript">


     var foo; // Here's the difference


    $(document).ready(function(){
     foo = function status_change(status,user_id)
    {
       alert(status+'------'+user_id);

     }
   });
 </script>
```